# How can I recursively count the number of non-whitespace characters in a string using C?

Tags: c

The main problem with this program is that it won't count the number of whitespaces in a string, even though it's supposed to decrement the count if it encounters a whitespace (it starts out with count set to the string's length). Am I not checking for whitespaces correctly (by checking for ' '), or is there something wrong with my recursion cases?

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>

// function to reverse string and count its length
int rPrint(char *str, int count)
{
   if(*str)
   {
       if(*str != ' ')   
           rPrint(str+1, count);
       else
           rPrint(str+1, count - 1);

       printf("%c", *str);
   }
   return count;
}

int main()
{
   char string[28] = "";
   int count = 0;

   printf("Please enter a string: ");
   gets(string);

   count = rPrint(string, strlen(string));

   printf("\nThe number of non-blank characters in the string is %d.", count);
}
```

Comment: While you return `count`, you don't *use* the returned value from recursive calls.

Comment: Minor point:  Technically, "whitespace" includes, in addition to blanks, tab characters, newline characters, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the return value of your recursive calls.

```
   if(*str != ' ')
       rPrint(str+1, count);
   else
       rPrint(str+1, count - 1);
```

should be

```
   if(*str != ' ')
       count = rPrint(str+1, count);
   else
       count = rPrint(str+1, count - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you recurse, you throw away the result.  Try

```
count = rPrint(str+1, count);
```

etc.

More generally, as a debugging method you should learn to put `printf()` statements into your functions to print out what they're doing....